# Retrieving JSON value from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have an issue with NSDictionary that is populated using JSON. The JSON data looks like this and am able to get the amount

```
Balance =  {
    amount = "33069.42";
    currencyCode = USD;
};

NSString *amtStr = [[account objectForKey:@"Balance"] valueForKey:@"amount"]);
NSString *formattedAmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", [amtStr floatValue]];
```

But, in some cases, there is no value for amount and instead amount has another NSDictionary as in the sample below

```
Balance =     {
    amount =         {
        nil = 1;
    };
    currencyCode =         {
        nil = true;
    };
};
```

and when I try to do the stringWithFormat

```
NSString *formattedAmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", [amtStr floatValue]];
```

is throwing

```
-[__NSCFDictionary floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a551e0
```

Any ideas on how to get the amount value in the second case? If the amount is nil, I need to set amtStr to 0.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: First I would try to figure out why you're getting that screwy JSON -- it's not normal.  In particular, a key name of "nil" strongly suggests that something got hosed up -- possibly some zombie storage.  (You should at least examine the original JSON, before it's deserialized, and possibly double-check with the other end.)  But if you determine that it's correct, you should use `isKindOfClass` as the others suggest.

Comment: Yeah, good point. I did check the data before I deserialized and that is how it was coming across. So I used the suggestions recommended below and got it working. Thank you everyone for your response.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you interrogate the folks at the other end -- it definitely looks like something is getting messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if `amtStr` is a string or not, before parsing the float:

```
id amtStr = [[account objectForKey:@"Balance"] valueForKey:@"amount"]);
if([amtStr isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] ){
   String *formattedAmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", [amtStr floatValue]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to test the class returned

```
id amt = [[account objectForKey:@"Balance"] valueForKey:@"amount"]);
if ([amt isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]
{
    NSString *amtStr = (NSString *)amt;
    NSString *formattedAmt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.2f", [amtStr floatValue]];
    //...
}
```

Comment: `id` already is a pointer to an object pointer ;) so your first line is wrong ;)

Comment: @HAS Oh this is embarrassing! I corrected it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, `amtStr` is a `NSDictionary` (despite being declared as a `NSString`), so `[amt isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]` would return true, and `[amt isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]` would return false.

Answer (score 1):

Don't assume that `amount` is always going to be a string. Check the object `amount` and see if it is an `NSDictionary` or a string

```
NSDictionary * balance = [account objectForKey@"Balance"];
id amountObject = [balance objectForKey:@"amount"];

if (amountObject != nil( {  

    if ([amountObject isKindOfClass:([NSDictionary class])]) {
        // amount is a dictionary
    } else if ([amountObject isKindOfClass:([NSString class])]) {
        // amount is a number
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule: When accessing data from encoded JSON that was received or read always double check the class of the objects, that you receive.